# typeid result in different compilers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++, typeid

I am watching the following [video](https://youtu.be/uX99t7GmuDc?list=PLs3KjaCtOwSZ2tbuV1hx8Xz-rFZTan2J1&t=321)

It is mentioned here that g++ will report an error for the following code:

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<typeinfo>
#include<iostream>
struct S
{
    std::vector<std::string> b ;
};
int main()
{
    S s;
    std::cout << typeid(S::b).name();
}
```

```sh
error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘S::b’
```

But I did not encounter this kind of error under msvc and clang. Who is right and why?
And why is it changed to

```cpp
typeid(&S::b).name();
```

Is the result correct afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gcc is wrong ([Bug 68604](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68604)). `S::b` is an id-expression referring to a non-static data member, which could be used only in unevaluated context. Gcc seems failing in taking this as unevaluated expression.

As the workaround you could:

```
std::cout << typeid(decltype(S::b)).name();
```

Note that in `typeid(&S::b).name();`, `&S::b` gives a pointer to member; the result is different with using `S::b`.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how you found this link quickly?
I searched for errors output by the compiler, but no such results were found

Comment: @fqq I searched on [GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) directly with the keyword *typeid non-static data member*.

Comment: wow, that's efficient.

Comment: `typeid` is in general *not* an unevaluated context.

Comment: and the Bugzilla links back to an older StackOverflow question which this duplicates.